# Limit of non linear recursive sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, recurrence-relations

Let $a_0:=0, a_n:=a_{n-1}^2+1 \; n \geq 1$, I've been trying to evaluate the following limit: $L:=\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}a_n^{\frac{1}{2^n}} $. This is not a homework problem so a closed form might not exist, however I have at least managed to show that the limit exists since the sequence is increasing and bounded above by the golden ratio. SAGE suggests that $L\approx 1.22590244352875$ and I've looked at a inverse symbolic caculator site but that has not been very informative. Any guesses or ideas would be helpful!

Comment: The standard answer is to do a lookup in OEIS. Your sequence is [sequence A003095](https://oeis.org/A003095). A link there leads to [OEIS sequence A076949](https://oeis.org/A076949) which is the decimal expansion of your constant and which you could have found with a lookup of its digits.